# qmake set platform toolset

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I'm using scripts to build my projects and open them with Visual Studio 2013 but now I got a project that has to be build with PlatformToolSet v100 (Visual Studio 2010). My question is: Is there a define or something that I've to add to the *.pro file or is there a parameter I've to use with qmake to create the right toolset? If not, is there any other way?

Comment: i'm using spec win32-msvc2010

Comment: So what's problem then?

Comment: that the generatex vcx still uses platformtoolset 120 but i need the v100 toolset here

Comment: Revise qmake.conf and its includes, clean & rebuild.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928293/vs2012-nmake-using-v110-xp-toolset